# How Code First used with Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

How Code First used with Entity Framework 4.1 ?I want to know how Database is manged and Model is used in Code First Approach.Thanks

Comment: I recommend you Google EF code first for getting started articles are read up on the subject, then if you have any specific questions ask them here.

Comment: There are tons and tons of articles on the web explaining what you have asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code-First Development enables a pretty sweet development workflow.  It enables you to:

1. Develop without ever having to open a designer or define an XML
   mapping file. Develop without ever having to open a designer or
   define an XML mapping file.
2. Define your model objects by simply writing “plain old classes” with no base classes required.
3. Use a “convention over configuration” approach that enables database persistence without explicitly configuring anything.
4. Optionally override the convention-based persistence and use a fluent code API to fully customize the persistence mapping.

Its a general question and lot of help is available on the internet.Following link will be helpful to implement Code First Approach.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh126815.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4

Answer (score 1):

With EF 4.1 the database is not managed. You can have it generate the database on your initial creation but EF 4.1 does not use Migrations. You could create a custom solution to manage the database piece but it may prove to be a pain and dangerous in a prod environment.

Not sure how familiar you are with EF but if you have not used it I would recommend as others have reading a tutorial or 3. Also, if possible I would use the newest version of EF that you can as a great deal has been updated since 4.1.

Here is a tutorial.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-code-first-walkthrough.aspx